# Remove the longest word and a punctuation with it if the word has it for each line in .txt file in C#

Tags: c#

I've a .txt file that has stuff writen like:

```
Hello, this is example
This is other, example.
Test, test, test.
```

I need to read each line and remove for each line the longest word and it's punctuation. So the result should be:

```
Hello, this is
This is other,
```

I understand how to find the longest word but I'm not sure if I'm reading seperate lines instead of whole text at once.

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Labaratorinis5
{
    class Program
    {
    const string CFd = "duomenys.txt";
    const string CFr = "rezultatai.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] skyrikliai = { ',', ',', '.', '?', '!', '(', ')', ';', ':',
            '\t' };

        if (File.Exists(CFr))
        {
            File.Delete(CFr);
        }

        Apdoroti(CFd, CFr, skyrikliai);
    }

    static void Apdoroti(string fvd, string fvr, char[] skyrikliai)
    {
        using (var frr = new StreamWriter(fvr, true,
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
        {
            string line;
            using (StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(fvd, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
            {
                while (((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
                {
                    frr.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Dmitry, I'm not sure the edit of the input is correct, because by his example "Hello" should have been removed as well as "example". This means he treat them as separate lines\inputs. Or his exampe is incorrect. Need more info

Comment: Why `"Hello, this is example"` has been turned into `"this is"`? Here `"example"` is the *longest* (7 characters) word, so the expected outcome is "Hello this is"

Comment: I think he treat every punct as separate line or input. in any case need more information to verify exactly extreme example. Which I'm not sure he grasp initially.

Answer (score 0):

To read separate lines, just read in characters till the `\n` newline character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the file line-by-line, it might be better to use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines)
instead of `StreamReader`. You would read all the lines in the file into an array, do your work on top of that array and afterwards use `File.WriteLines` to write the result back, potentially saving you a lot of effort with file management.

An example:

```
static void Apdoroti(string fvd, string fvr, char[] skyrikliai)
{
    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fvd);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < fileLine.Length; ++i)
    {
        //Do something with each line
        fileLines[i] = RemoveLongestWord(fileLines[i]); 
    }
    
    File.WriteAllLines(fvr, fileLines, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this remove the word only once in one line? Would I need first to find longest word length and then use if statement to find if all words that are the lenght size removed?

Comment: You asked about ways to read and write all lines of a file, which is what my answer is about. What you do with the individual lines is up to you

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define *word*. Let

> Word be a sequence of `a..z` or `A..Z` characters.

Now we are ready to *match* words with a help of *regular expressions*.

```
   Regex.Matches(text, "[A-Za-z]+");
```

We can use *Linq* to remove all words of maximum Length:

```
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   ...

   private static Regex s_Words = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+"); 

   private static string SolveLine(string line) {
     string[] words = s_Words
       .Matches(line)
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(match => match.Value)
       .ToArray();

     if (words.Length <= 0) // no word line case
       return "";

     int maxLength = words.Max(word => word.Length);

     return string.Join(" ", words.Where(word => word.Length < maxLength));    
   }
```

Time to process the entire file:

```
   var data = File
     .ReadLines("duomenys.txt")
     .Select(line => SolveLine(line));

   File.WriteAllLines("rezultatai.txt", data);
```